# Is it okay to have close friendships with non Muslims?

Tags: practical-islam, non-muslim, friendship

Assalamualaikum.My sister has some of her friends from different communities and she gets along quite well with them.She is in good friendship with each of them.But my mom, getting some issues with it,always says"She will get  these non Muslims friends as companions in Maidan-e-Hashr rather than 
people from Muslim Ummah".Would someone please let me know the authenticity of this statement?Does Islam permit a Muslim to have friendship with a non Muslim?If yes,then to what extent can I have friendship with them?

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers on this topic on the site. And a major message in the qur'an is the coexistence and cultural exchange between humans so it is certainly not haram by default. But rather wanted.

Comment: If they aren't muslims, and specially if they do haram things, it's haram and she will be driven away from Islam. Having a simple (not too much close) friendship is better.